# How to decrease PHP time limit in safe mode?

Tags: php

Let's say I was running external script I have no access to (please note that this question is not asking what are the security risks of doing so) and I want it to stop in 2 seconds no matter what.

Of course I don't want to adit my `php.ini` on order to do that. Neither I want to disable safe mode to enable [`set_time_limit`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Is there a workaround that doesn't hit performance drastically?

I noted performance to avoid answer that suggests getting the code as string and *eviluating* it *per partes*. Generally performance is *not* important.

Comment: You might want to consider a `tick` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php

Comment: I tried to create something based upon that. Is there any reason why tick callback wouldn't get called and/or the tick register would silently fail?

Comment: Did you remember to declare ticks? http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php

Comment: safe mode is widely held to be useless/wrong, was deprecated in 5.3 and removed in 5.4 - is there a reason you're using it at all?

Comment: I assumed the `set_time_limit` will not be running on webhosting. I thought safe mode is default mode that prevents dangerous things from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple class that accomplishes the task using ticks as suggested by [@Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345016/how-to-decrease-php-time-limit-in-safe-mode/24350463#comment37638010_24345016). I have also [placed in on GitHub](https://github.com/Darker/PHPClasses/blob/master/set_time_limit_safe.php) if any improvements were suggested.

```
declare(ticks=1);
//You don't need to use that function
function set_time_limit_safe($limit) {
  if(!is_numeric($limit))
    trigger_error("set_time_limit_safe() expects parameter 1 to be numeric value, ". gettype($limit)." given", E_USER_WARNING);
  TimeLimit::set($limit);
}
//I'm using class to have the possibility of private static that's shared between both
//set function and the callback
class TimeLimit {
    //Default value for limit
    private static $limit = 30;
    //When the limit is registered, this is set to current time for later comparisons
    private static $reg_time = -1;
    //Boolean to determine whether callback is already registered or not
    private static $registered = false;
    /**
* Sets the time limit and registers callback
* @param float $limit limiting time in seconds
* @return null
**/
    public static function set($limit) {
      //echo "Setting time limit!<br />";
      self::$limit = $limit;
      //Seconds as float
      self::$reg_time = microtime(true);
      //Only register once
      if(!self::$registered) {
        register_tick_function(array('TimeLimit', 'tick_cb'));
        //echo "Registering tick function!<br />";
        self::$registered = true;
      }
    }
    /**
* The callback
* You can disable the limit by unregistering this function
**/
    public static function tick_cb() {
      $time = microtime(true);
      //echo "Tick!!!<br />";
      if($time-self::$reg_time>=self::$limit) {
        trigger_error("User defined maximum execution time of ".self::$limit." seconds exceeded.", E_USER_ERROR);
        //In case error callback had let the error through
        exit;
      }
    }
}

//Testing code
set_time_limit_safe(1.5);

while(true) {
}
```

I need to know how can this be by-passed though.